# Large response with akka http

Tags: scala, akka-http

I'm testing akka-http with average sized responses around ~156KB. If I run the test sequentially I can get the response in client which implemented with akka-http also.

But if I run concurrent requests (8 request) on end point, I only get the response for first three.

Test run in local.

Here is the server code;

```
val text = Source.fromInputStream(getClass.getResourceAsStream("/data/data.txt")).mkString

  val route =
    path("build") {
      get {
        complete {
          Future {
            println("Finished")
            //HttpEntity.Strict(ContentTypes.`text/html(UTF-8)`, ByteString(text))
            HttpEntity(ContentTypes.`text/html(UTF-8)`, text)
          }

        }
      }
    }
```

Here is the client code;

```
(1 to 8).map { i =>
    val res = buildRequest.map { br =>
          println(br)
          TestResult(true, startTime, System.currentTimeMillis, d, None)
        }.recoverWith { case t =>
          println(t)
          Future.successful(TestResult(false, startTime, System.currentTimeMillis, d, Some(t.getMessage)))
        }
}

..
..

def buildRequest =  Source.single(HttpRequest(uri = "/build") -> 1)
  .via(poolClientFlow)
  .runWith(Sink.head)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The client code you included doesn't consume the response's entity, which may lead to the problems you are experiencing. You need to either consume the whole response entity or discard it. Further explanation about this issue and how to resolve it is available [here](http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka-http/10.0.5/scala/http/implications-of-streaming-http-entity.html#implications-of-streaming-http-entities).